# Query to fetch emails tracked in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

Is there a way to query tracked emails in CRM 2011 or above using SQL(Filtered Views)? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an advanced find against email messages.

Add a filter for 'Tracking Token' contains data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If we want to know emails tracked specific to contact or account, will Tracking Token is sufficient or we need to look at activity party?

Comment: Probably best to look at the activity party as well.